# Navigation menu dont work while overriding back button HTML 5 History API

Tags: html5-history

I am new with the history API.

Navigation menu stops working when page loads in chrome, In firefox it works first time but then again navigation menu stops working. but when I comment the function, History API doesn't work. Everything else works fine. No JS or Ajax errors.

Here is the function that causes the problem :

```
 $(window).bind('popstate', function() {
    $.ajax({url:location.pathname,success: function(data){
      $('#ttl').html(data);
    }});
  });
```

check out here : http://ddvsdakor.com/test/services/logo-designing-and-branding.w

Comment: What do you mean: "Doesn't work"?

Comment: There's nothing overtly wrong with that function. Does your navigation run on JS and maybe the AJAX request is failing and blowing the rest of your JS on the page?

Comment: I use bootstrap. I have dropdown menu. When I click on it, it doesn't show menu.

Comment: no JS or ajax errors. it works completely fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your function might have had an extra brace in there. Reworked it using non-deprecated syntax.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function(){
    $.ajax({ url: location.pathname })
        .done(function(data){ $('#ttl').html(data); });
});
```

Comment: Sorry sir, It didn't fixed my issue.

Comment: check out here : http://ddvsdakor.com/test/services/logo-designing-and-branding.w

Comment: Looks like the CSS is just missing to activate the dropdown-menu on hover.

Comment: No sir, when I dont Include above function, it works. there is no CSS problem.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following syntax, but I don't use history.js. I've written my own routing engine to avoid all kinds of those issues.

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
        $.ajax({
                url: location.href,
                success: function(content) {
                    $('body>#content').css({ opacity: 0 });
                    $('body>#content').html(content);
                    $('body>#content').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 300, 'swing');
                },
                cache: false
        });
        return false;
    });
```

I've explained my way of using HTML 5 history API , in this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690329/what-kind-of-questions-should-be-asked-when-choosing-between-straight-mvc4-and-a/18699732#18699732)

Comment: I will let you know after I test your function.